# Regenerate (Clean) .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

How to regenerate `.gitmodules` to eliminate all entries that don't exist?

Also, is it possible to update it with all submodules listed under `.git/modules`, that are not already present?

Although, this should not have happened if the submodules were properly removed using `git rm`, but unfortunately, this was not the case.